# BeautifulSoup parsing is not complete while Response.content is returning correct html page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

hi i'm trying to find all links in webpage and using requests the response content are all ok except when i use beautiful soup it doesn't show the full html nor it works well with it, where is the problem?

here is the code:

```py
url = f'https://subf2m.co/subtitles/tenet/farsi_persian'
r = s.get(url, headers=headers);
print(r.content) #is returning correct html
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml") #is not complete and i tried html parsing too
print(soup)
atags = soup.find_all("a")
```

not working, where is the problem

Comment: What is your expected output? I am able to get all the 27 subtitle links using the code above.

Comment: [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @TanishqChaudhary i'm supposed to get all 27 links but i can only see it in r.content and when i parse it with beautifulsoup the html only returns the last part of html file and only one link. did you recieve all links with beautiful soup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get all 27 links.

Code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = f'https://subf2m.co/subtitles/tenet/farsi_persian'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
atags = soup.find_all("a", attrs={'class': 'download'})

for atag in atags:
    print(atag['href'])

print(len(atags))
```

Output:

```
/subtitles/tenet/farsi_persian/2344206
/subtitles/tenet/farsi_persian/2303056
...
/subtitles/tenet/farsi_persian/2111345
27
```

Comment: thanx it solved the problem, i didn't realized i was using requests.Session() instead of requests.get

Comment: Glad I could help. You can upvote and/or mark the answer as selected if you found it useful.